# Ignore certain methods when inheriting from classes

Tags: php, oop

I'm learning oop and practicing the concepts with PHP.
What I'm trying to do is to have a class `Human` and a class `Dog`. Class `Human` will have two properties: `$name:string` and `$age:int`. Class `Human` is declared first, having a method `speak()`. My problem is when `Dog` extends from `Humans`, I want it to have everything from `Human` except for the method `speak()`, where it would be replaced by its unique method `bark()`. From what I've searched, a solution would be to set `speak()` to `private`, then `Dog` wouldn't inherit it. However, when assigning `Human` to `$person`, `speak()` is also not accessible since it's private. This is just a practice for me to understand oop. What should I do in terms of the best practices, if this were a real software? Again, I'm a beginner at oop. Thanks!

Here's my code:

```
<?php

    class Human {
      public $name;
      public $age;

      public function __construct($name, $age) {
        $this->name = $name;
        $this->age = $age;
      }

      public function speak() {

      }
    }

    class Dog extends Human {
      public function bark() {

      }
    }

    $people = array();
    $dogs = array();

    array_push($dogs, new Dog("Rocky", 4));
    array_push($people, new Human("Carlos", 21));

    $people[0]->speak();
    $dogs[0]->bark();

?>
```

Comment: A dog isn't a human, so your `class Dog` should not extend `class Human`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In terms of OOP, it doesnt make any sense a Dog extends a Human. Think about it, it just doesnt make any sense. What you can do is actually define an abstract class or a interface that both Dog and Human extends from. Like this:

```
abstract class Animal 
{
     abstract public function communicate();
     ...anyOtherMethods that are commom between dogs and Humans
}

class Human extends Animal 
{
     public function communicate()
     {
        echo 'speak';
     }
}

class Dog extends Animal
{

     public function communicate()
     {
        echo 'bark';
     }
}

(new Dog)->communicate(); // bark
(new Human)->communicate(); //speak
```

Comment: Maybe that was a bad example, but imagine a class that shares some properties and methods with another. What should one not to inherit a specific method, but also keeps the original one to be able to use it? If that happens, it means it's been designed badly?

Comment: Yes, probably is a bad design. There is no such thing of "inherit just a set of methods and/or attributes". If you're having that problem, maybe you need to break down your classes into separate ones because it's having more responsabilities than it should.